# Custom Admin Route giving 404

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Im trying to create a custom route on the administration, but is not working, it gives me a 404.

config.xml:

```
<global>
...
</global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <cloud_magni>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cloud_Magni</module>
                    <frontName>secondinvoice</frontName>
                </args>
            </cloud_magni>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Cloud/Magni/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php

```
class Cloud_Magni_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function sayHelloAction(){
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

The url im accessing is:

```
https://somedomain.com/index.php/admin/secondinvoice/sayHello/key/018460841df56cd3a7fbe2d720d750d2/
```

Comment: have u get url via admin menu or direct pass url in browser?

Comment: can u pls share your full config.xml file code?

Answer (score 1):

Every time when you have problem with routing use Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::_validateControllerClassName function to debug controller file path and classname

Comment: Great Tip Stephan!

Answer (score 0):

Change in your config.xml

...

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <namespace before="Mage_Adminhtml">NameSpace_Module_Adminhtml</namespace>
                </modules>
                <frontName>secondinvoice</frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**Replace your `namespace` to your NAMESPACE and `NameSpace_Module` to your own.**

**UPDATE**

change this `class Cloud_Magni_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

to

`class Cloud_Magni_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

Comment: is not working :S

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: Already made this change, but still no success, have no idea of the problem is the path of the route

Comment: Try to add the menu for this controller and access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <cloud_magni>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cloud_Magni</module>
                    <frontName>secondinvoice</frontName>
                </args>
            </cloud_magni>
        </routers>
   </admin>
   ...
   ...
   ...   
</config>
```

**IndexController.php**

> app\code\local\Cloud\Magni\controllers\Adminhtml\IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Cloud_Magni_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Method for render layout
     */
    public function sayHelloAction()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
        die;
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Note:** If your access url via admin top menu then used below code in action tag in `config.xml` or `adminhtml.xml`

```
<action>secondinvoice/adminhtml_index/sayHello</action>
```

If your used in php & pthml then use below code

```
$this->getUrl('secondinvoice/adminhtml_index/sayHello', array('_current'=>true));
```

For eg.  `<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('secondinvoice/adminhtml_index/sayHello', array('_current'=>true));   ?>">Say Hello</a>`